# What is ideal place for storing user sessions openldap or redis

Tags: caching, redis, ldap, openldap, session-cache

I am using openLDAP storing users. where should I keep user session details as it we need to track few user details for a session. What is Ideal place to store user sessions?

Thank you...

Comment: flagging it as off-topic because: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @bitoiu No off-site resource is being requested here. The question is a simple choice between OpenLDAP and 'redis'.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"- in this case a library or tool.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the fact that the question is off-topic I'd use redis as it is fast and simple. You'd only need a key-value store for keeping session information and not a fully grown directory server. LDAP might be fast in getting Information out of it, but you would need to put the information in first and update those informations on a regular basis which isn't what LDAP has been designed for.